# res.Data.pipe is not a function error message

Tags: typescript

I keep getting the following error on Angular 6:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: res.Data.pipe is not a function
```

This is my code here:

```
this._prices.getHistoricalPrices(this.symbol, prefix, timeLimit, aggregate).subscribe(res => {
  if (environment.production === false) {
    console.log(res.Data);
    console.log(res.Data.length);
  }

  priceChart = res.Data.pipe(map(res.close));
  allDates = res.Data.pipe(map(res.time));

  if (environment.production === false) {
    console.log(priceChart);
  }

  cryptoDates = [];
  allDates.forEach(() => {
    const jsDate = new Date(res * 1000);
    cryptoDates.push(jsDate.toLocaleTimeString([], { day: 'numeric', month: 'short', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }));
  });

  // Draw new chart

  this.chart = new Chart(canvasId, {
    type: 'LineWithLine',
    data: {
      labels: cryptoDates,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: priceChart,
          borderColor: '#60acf3',
          cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
          fill: false
        }
      ]
    },
    options: this.chartOptions
  });
});
```

I've included a [fuller segment here](https://pastebin.com/wpGDWcAx). An exampple of the page I am trying to create is [here](https://crypto.kris2d.info/xrp).

Comment: res.Data seems to be an array. Arrays don't have a pipe() method. Hence the error.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried `priceChart = res['Data'].map(res.close); allDates = res['Data'].map(res.time);` but get this error message: `ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a function at Array.map (<anonymous>)`. What does it mean and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Depending on which line causes that error, it means that res.close is not a function, or that res.time is not a function. I have the feeling you're trying random things. Don't. read the documentation of Array.map(), and the documentation/source code of your `res` object.